# Salesforce openID connect google failed login attempts

Tags: google-oauth, google-openid

I have successfully integrated my a salesforce instance with openID Connect to google as CSP. I am wondering if there is any way by which I can restrict the number of failed login attempts (3 to 4 times) at google side?

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Guys can someone comment please. I am looking forward for your guidance. Thank you.

Comment: No, you can't do this on the Google side.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do this on the Google side.

This is not part of the OpenID Connect spec, nor is it something Google supports outside the spec.